# Select list with most certain entries

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following database

[image]

and I would like to select the playlist that has most songs of AC/DC, but my script does not work.

My script:

```
SELECT playlist.Name
FROM playlist
INNER JOIN playlisttrack
ON playlist.PlaylistId = playlisttrack.PlaylistId
INNER JOIN track
ON playlisttrack.TrackId = track.TrackId
INNER JOIN album
ON track.AlbumId = album.AlbumId
WHERE ArtistId = 1;
```

Comment: what is the `artist` in `WHERE artist.ArtistId = 1;` it is not defined anywhere before

Comment: AC/DC has an Id 1 and I would like to find the playlist with most of their songs.

Comment: OK but you're not joining track with album, so you have no way to access the ArtistId

Comment: @amenadiel I edited the code, but it still does not work.

Comment: but it should give you a lot of playlist names, right? so the next step would be to group by playlist name and id

Comment: @amenadiel It should give me the name of the playlist, only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a while since I've done MySql but it should be pretty close to this.

```
SELECT playlist.Name
FROM playlist
INNER JOIN playlisttrack
ON playlist.PlaylistId = playlisttrack.PlaylistId
INNER JOIN track
ON playlisttrack.TrackId = track.TrackId
INNER JOIN album
ON track.AlbumId = album.AlbumId
WHERE album.ArtistId = 1
GROUP BY playlist.PlayListId, playlist.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Note that the `Group By` is lumping your playlists together (and I'm including PlayListId as you've done nothing to indicate that your Names are unique)

I'm doing `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` to get the count within each playlist, then I'm doing `LIMIT 1` to just get the first one.